# Laravel relation search function

Tags: php, laravel, search, relation

I know where the following error is coming from but I do not know how to fix it.

The error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'expenses.date' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `expenses_sections` where `expenses`.`date` LIKE %2015-12%)

What is causing it (in my controller):

```
if($view === 'section') {
    $query = Section::query();
        $query->with(['expenses' => function($query) use ($search){
            $query->where('date', 'LIKE', '%2015-' . $search . '%')->get();
        }]);
}
```

I have a select menu which I use to change the layout of the page. I have another select menu which I use to display results from a certain month only. The above error is what I am getting when I select a month, because the query is looking in the wrong table (because of the above code). The results are displayed using a relation between Expenses and Sections. What I basically want is to search for results in the `expenses` table, instead of the `expenses_sections` table, ofcourse without breaking the relation, because based on the relation, my layout is being displayed.

Expense Model:

```
class Expense extends Model
{
    public function section()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Http\Models\Expenses\Section');
    }
}
```

Section Model:

```
class Section extends Model
{
    public function expenses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Http\Models\Expenses\Expense');
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `expense` has a `date` field?

Comment: If you have expenses_sections that has expenses_id and section_id, you should be using hasManyThrough(), but I always struggle to get these working first time so rather than me trying to answer it, have a read of this pending a better reply: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: Awesome, it's better to ofcourse read it myself instead of getting an answer I can use immediately, so I thank you! :)

Comment: @RonBrouwers - actually I could be very wrong there. Have a look at the section above that about pivot tables. I think I should go to bed now...

Comment: I know about pivot tables but I haven't checked out the hasManyThrough yet, so either way I will learn something which is my ultimate goal :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query constraints should always return the query builder instance. You should not call `get` within your closure so try fixing it like this:

```
$query = Section::query();
$query->with(['expenses' => function($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where('date', 'LIKE', '%2015-' . $search . '%');
}]);
```

This will fetch all sections and eager load the relationships. The ones that don't fit the constraints will just have an empty `expenses` relationship. If you only want sections that fit the constraints, then you should use [`whereHas`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) method.

```
$query = Section::query();
$query->with('expenses')->whereHas('expenses', function($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where('date', 'LIKE', '%2015-' . $search . '%');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found that the error was somewhere else, so I fixed it myself after trying to use your answer. Still marked this as accepted though.